# ANTLR4: How to control class hierarchy?

Tags: java, antlr

How to configure ANTLR4 to **not** generate a parent class?

Given grammar `MyGrammar`

```
statement: 'do' | 'check';
```

ANTLR4 generates

```
class MyGrammar {
    class StatementContext {}
}
```

Since ANTLR4 generates a parent class for all `XXXContext` classes, this class name must be used in any usages as well. So I must write

```
MyGrammar.StatementContext node = ...;
```

and cannot simply write

```
NodeContext node = ...;
```

This is big enough of a deal, as it will pollute my code with extra characters that don't add any readability. As such, it downgrades readability, thus comprehensibility and debuggability, et cetera.

So, how can I make the grammar `MyGrammar`

```
statement: 'do' | 'check';
```

have ANTLR4 generate

```
class StatementContext {} // look ma: no parent MyGrammar class!
```

Comment: A [mcve] would help us understand the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as that: you cannot change the way classes are generated. It's a carefully arranged ensemble and changing that would break many things.